# Magento2 Customer login Invalid request received

Tags: magento2, customer-registration, customer-login, xdebug

Magento2 Customer login Invalid request received

[image]

When i try Register customer, i receive similar kind of error.

```
"Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\CreatePost\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /var/www/html/airbnb/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/CreatePost.php:327)"} []
```

On Login page i receive this error as shoon in screen shot too.

```
Request validation failed for action "Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost\Interceptor" {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\InvalidRequestException(code: 0): Invalid request received at /var/www/html/airbnb/app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/LoginPost.php:158)"} []
```

Last time register have worked when i changed the permission of *Generated* folder to 777

[image]

when i run Xdebug, and submit customer login form, i see this error.
[image]

Comment: Change the permission to var folder to 777.

Comment: sudo chmod 777 airbnb/var    I run this command but still same error.

Comment: Have you created that third party extension for any customization and overide that things into that one?

Comment: run this command -   sudo chmod 777 -R var/  that means set 777 to all folder under var folder

Comment: Can you please share your controller code

Answer (score 1):

Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page

This is the error.
Magento has a Form Key to tackle spamming issues.

It looks like your form Key has expired. Just check the Age of Form Key.

Comment: where i can check formkey age? in which file or table?

Comment: php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 86400  this values are internally used by cookies and form keys

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my local vertualhost name. Name should be in 2 parts, seperated by a Dot(.) I was running it like http://stayingspacelocal/ somebody in stackoverflow told that it should be split by Dot. Dot is necessary otherwise that problem will occure. Than i changed my local vertual host to http://stayingspace.local/ and the issue is fixed.